# Por que a linguagem SQL varia de SGBD para SGBD?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite

Eu estava acostumado a usar SQL para projetos Web, sempre utilizando MySQL.

Um dia precisei escrever um programa em C++ que utilizava bancos de dados. De início escolhi SQLite porém precisava que outros computadores na rede se conectassem ao banco de dados.

Assim, optei pelo PostgreSQL por ser *open source*, porém nunca tinha usado antes> Logo quando fui criar minha primeira tabela notei algo de diferente, os "schemas" e no lugar do `AUTO_INCREMENT` PostgreSQL utiliza `SERIAL`.

Se a linguagem é padronizada então por que ela varia em cada um dos sistemas?

Comment: É padronizada até certo ponto. Não 100%, então os "manipuladores" tem alguns "detalhes" diferentes. Você quer vender um produto, você tem uma lista de requisitos padrões, mas isso não impede de ter detalhes seus, se não seria TUDO igual, e isso nem teria como!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O motivo exato é difícil definir, é assim porque se tornou assim. Provavelmente porque cada um achou que aquilo atendia melhor suas necessidades. É uma questão em parte técnica e parte comercial (*lock-in*).

A linguagem SQL ANSI ou ISO é uma só, mas segue-a estritamente quem quer, e ninguém quis. De certa forma o correto é chamar cada SQL com um nome específico e alguns chamam mesmo, mas as pessoas resolveram fazer de conta que não e usam o nome SQL puro para tudo.

Mas é um erro das pessoas usarem o nome de forma equivocada, e isso passa uma impressão errada. Quando alguém pergunta aqui poderia dizer de qual SQL está falando. Então entenda que não tem uma SQL, tem várias.

SQL é uma linguagem definida por comitê, e um pouco fora da realidade do mercado, então ela só existe padronizada no papel. Inclusive porque começou tudo errado. A linguagem é complexa demais para conseguir ser seguida e é ambígua ou omissa em certas coisas.

Tem hora que a indústria deveria repensar e criar algo melhor pelo menos como opção de uso. O mesmo vale para HMTL/CSS e outras coisas erradas.

Por marketing os SGDBs dizem adotar o padrão, mas só parcialmente, e mesmo assim um bem antigo (é comum adotarem o [SQL-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) - quando começaram se preocupar com isso e começou fazer sentido - algumas coisas selecionadas mais modernas, mas até esses mais básicos tem exceções do que não se conformam). Isso é meio sacanagem. Esqueça a falácia que SQL é padronizada, ela deveria ser, na prática não é. Note que mesmo o padrão tem como nome completo o ano da especificação.

O [SQL-99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999) já tem coisas que são complicadas de implementar ou não unânimes da sua utilidade. O [SQL-2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003) passou ter recursos que logo em seguida começaram achar má ideia, ou começaram tirar coisas que antes foram mal definidas, o que já vai quebrando a credibilidade do comitê. E tiveram que arrumar algumas coisas no [SQL-2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2006). Depois veio o [SQL-2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008) com algumas novidades. E depois o [SQL-2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) com funções temporais. Agora estamos no [SQL-2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2016) consertando erros anteriores.

Parte do problema poderia ser resolvido, mas parte não, porque a linguagem não pode ser usada igual no produto, principalmente em produto antigo que começou de uma forma e o padrão estabeleceu diferente depois, o comitê sempre corre atrás e quando o padrão é publicado quem implementou diferente não pode mudar mais pela base rodando.

É diferente de linguagem de programação que é feita para rodar em computador para mandar ele executar algo. **SQL é declarativa** para indicar o que quer de resultado e a implementação de onde rodará influencia seu jeito de funcionar. E piora o fato de não ter um certificador, quem diz que atende o padrão é o fornecedor.

MySQL é um enorme ofensor do padrão, nunca ligou pra ser diferente.

O PostgreSQL é considerado bastante próximo do padrão. O SQLite também é no que ele implementa. Em geral os fornecedores mudam a sintaxe e semântica do que fazem. Alguns aceitam a sintaxe padrão, mas possuem semântica vazia ou alterada, o que é muito pior.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado, eu estava pensando em comprar um curso ou um livro de SQL para poder dominar de fato a linguagem, depois disso é bom escolher um curso de mysql já que é o mais usado para projetos.